# On submodile update, don't fetch non-submodule files

Tags: git

I'm a little confused on how to add and eventually clone files I've added to a submodule.

I have a private git repo which within it has a submodule pointing to a public github repo. Within this repo, I add a single new file and commit it. I go back up to the main private project repo and commit and push the change. Everything merges without issue. Note, I do not want to push this new file into the public github. I only want it in my private repo.

Here's where the issue starts.
Say a user clones the repo. Then does a **submodule init**. After that, the **submodule update** fails. It fails because it's trying to download the commit id for that new file I added from the public github site. The file isn't on that public repo (nor do I want it to be there), it's only in the private repo.

Is there some way to tell git to download only the latest commit which is present in the public repo? Perhaps the way I'm going about committing and push the changes is the issue?

What drew me to use submodules is that I would also like to "resync" with the github project.

Is this even a valid use case for submodules in git?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking if you want to add your own files to the submodule then you should fork it. If the public repo lives on GitHub that is a very easy procedure.

So you create your fork, push the commit there and then point you submodule to this URL instead.

Comment: I think something like that is the long term plan, but I would not be allowed to push these kinds of files out on github. Even if the repo is marked as private on github. For the time being anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found my answer. Submodule is not the way to go. What I'm going to do (and appears to be working for me) is to setup a remote which points to these public github repos. Checkout a branch, and then merge those branches into my private repo using a sub-tree merge strategy.

If I need to resync with the public git repo, I checkout the branch, do a git pull, and merge it into the branch for my private repo.

This is described here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging